# How to mirror iframe without loading the same URL twice? CSS doesn't activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have two iframes side by side and want only 1st one to be loading URL. After 1st one finishes loading, I want 2nd iframe to have the same content, without loading the same URL. Here is what I tried:

Testing here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#iframeID1').on('load', function() {
        $('#iframeID2').contents().find('html').html($('#iframeID1').contents().find('html').html());
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="iframeID1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="180px" height="512" align="left">
    </iframe>

  <iframe id="iframeID2" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="180px" height="512" align="middle">
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

However, this is what 2nd iframe (on the right) shows (fails to load CSS?):

[image]

Comment: *" without loading the same URL"* ... that is the only other option and probably the best one. Perhaps you should be using ajax to do whatever it is you are doing instead

Comment: @charlietfl why? It's almost working, we just need to activate CSS somehow. I really need it to do like that.

Comment: There is no simple way to do what you are asking is why. What you are doing is very unorthodox

Comment: I know it's unorthodox, that's where stackoverflow geniuses will come in

Comment: Won't get much more help until you explain your use case more. Still betting this whole approach is wrong and there are better ways to solve the higher level problem

Answer (score 0):

Non jquery but why don't you read the HTML from the page and then dynamically create the second iframe using something like...

```
Iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
Iframe.contentWindow.document.write(htmlfromfirstiframe);
Iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: would you be able to provide an example in jQuery? I'm using it for only 1 day now, don't know how to translate this